# execute jquery inside div element only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using console to execute a jquery command, but I want to execute it within a div element and not the entire page, how could i do this?

div element is = to

```
 <div class="content">
 </div>
```

then inside that div I want to execute via console

```
 $('#').show();
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. What does it mean to execute a jquery within an element?

Comment: `$('#')` doesn't make sense. `#` has to be followed by an ID.

Comment: explain the question clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can select element within another element like this:
`$('outerElementSelector innerElementSelector')`,
or like this:
`$('outerElementSelector').find('innerElementSelector')`,
or like this:
`$('innerElementSelector ', outerElement or 'outerElementSelector')`

For example if you want to select element with class 'someelement' that is located inside div with class 'content', you can use any of these selectors listed below

```
<div class='content'>
    <div class='someelement'></div>
</div>
<div class='someelement'></div>
```

- 1.

  ```
  $('.content .someelement')
  ```
- 2.

  ```
  $('.content').find('.someelement')
  ```
- 3.

  ```
  $('.someelement', '.content')
  ```
- 4.

  ```
  var outerEl = $('.content')
  $('.someelement', outerEl)
  ```